# Click the element does not invoke next event

Tags: selenium

The problem is when the element is clicked, it does not open the pop-up it is suppose to open.The floating menu disappears and hence fails on the next step

I used

```
System.out.println("RateType_selected");
```

to validate the click

(The element which this command clicks is on a floating menu and disappears if the page scroll)

I am not scrolling the page just clicking the element to open the pop-up but the menu disappears when clicked

```
// Command Element to open the floating menu
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".create-for-no-item .create-new.add-rate")).click();

// Command to click on the floating menu element to open popup 


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='new-item popup-opener active-new-list-item']//span[@class='new-text'][contains(text(),'Recurring Rate')]")).click();  

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".action-dropdown-button:nth-child(3) > .create-new")).click();


// Tried Javascript as well

WebElement addRatetype = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".action-dropdown-button:nth-child(3) > .create-new"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", addRatetype);



((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".action-dropdown-button:nth-child(3) > .create-new")));
```

// Also, tried the try catch

```
try {
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".action-dropdown-button:nth-child(3) > .create-new")).click();
                System.out.println("Clicked on Recurring rate");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a new locator to find the element and now licks everytime

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='create-for-no-item product-create rate sdfcddm need-to-hide-dropdown-panel']//li[2]")).click();
```